# It's Life, Jim, but not as we know it

Tags: king-of-the-hill, game-of-life

You probably know *Conway's Game of Life*, the famous cellular automaton invented by mathematician John Conway. *Life* is a set of rules that, together, allow you to simulate a two-dimensional board of cells. The rules decide which cells on the board live and  which ones die. With some imagination, you could say that *Life* is a zero-player game: a game with the objective to find patterns with interesting behavior, like the famous glider.

[image: Glider]

A zero-player game... Until today. You are to write a program that plays the Game of Life - and plays it to win, King of the Hill-style. Your opponent (singular) of course tries to do the same. The winner is either the last bot with any live cells, or the player with the most live cells after 10000 generations.

### Game rules

The rules are *almost* the same as normal (B3/S23) Life:

- A live cell with fewer than two friendly neighbors dies from starvation.
- A live cell with two or three friendly neighbors survives.
- A live cell with more than three friendly neighbors dies from overpopulation.
- A dead cell with exactly three neighbors of the same player comes alive to fight for that player *provided there are no enemy neighbors*.

...but after each generation, both you and your opponent get the opportunity to intervene. You can awake up to a maximum of 30 cells to fight for you. (Who goes first is decided by the server.)

The board is a (x,y) cells square. All squares are initially dead. The borders do not wrap around (this is not a torus-shaped world) and are permanently dead.

This is is a contest in the spirit of *Battlebots* and *Core Wars*. There is a central server that will run bots and it can be found [here](https://github.com/muddyfish/PPCG-Life)

### Protocol

The arena server speaks a simple JSON protocol communicated through argv

Where Values is a JSON encoded string

- `y_size`: the maximum y coords of tiles before they vanish
- `x_size`: the maximum x coords of tiles before they vanish
- `tick_id`: the current tick number
- `board`: a dictionary with keys in the form '(y,x)' and values in the form `bot_id` (int)
- `bot_id`: tiles in the board with this id are yours

Example:

```
 {"y_size":2000,"x_size":2000,"board":{},"bot_id":1,"tick_id":1}
```

Telling the server your choice:

- Send the server a list of tiles to turn to your colour.
- Only those that are empty will be changed
- Nested coords list format

  - `[[0,0], [0,1], [100,22]...]`

NOTE: Your bot doesn't have to update the tiles at all - the server does the updating itself

### Competition rules

- If your implementation fails to follow the protocol, the turn it does will be forfeited; The server will assume no change in state
- You are not allowed to willfully take advantage of a fault in the arena server.
- Have your AI decide on moves in a sane time. Please send your next move as  fast as reasonably possible.
- Finally, please be nice to the server. It's there for your enjoyment.
- Not following these rules can lead to disqualification.
- In the event of a tie, both players have 1 win added to their total

### Running the controller yourself

The source for the controller can be found [here](https://github.com/muddyfish/PPCG-Life). There are 2 ways of running the controller:

- Competition mode (terminal)

  - Setup with `python3 get_answers.py`
  - Run an all v all competition with each bot pitting it against every other.
- Testing mode (GUI)

  - Run `python3 nice_gui.py`
  - Click `Pull Answers`
  - If you want to add your own answer to try it before posting, click `File -> Add manual answer` and find the file and choose the language it's written in.
  - If your language isn't present ping me and I'll try to get it installed on the server I will run it on (installation and running instructions would be nice too!)
  - Choose 2 bots to pit against each other
  - Click `Run`
  - Watch the game...
- Installation

  - Requires python3
  - get_answers requires bs4 and html5lib
  - controller requires a way of running .sh files (MinGW on windows)

[image: Example image of app]

### Scoring

The bot with the most wins starting from <s>`12/07/2016` (12th July)</s>   `14/07/2016` (14th July, couldn't work out how to run a bot) wins.

---

#### Help with the controller/gui can be asked in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41885/discussion-between-fawful-and-kevin-lau-not-kenny)

---

This question has been in development since 2014 and was the most upvoted question in the sandbox. Special Thanks goes to [Wander Nauta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19075/wander-nauta) (original author and concept), [PPCG Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) (comments and help) and anyone who commented in the [sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1332/32686) (more comments).

Comment: Huh, I thought this would never make it out of the sandbox. Great!

Comment: Typo: _12/06/2016 (12th July)_

Comment: so you didn't use my server?

Comment: @muddyfish sorry- this seems like tech support, but the gui is blank, and the get_answers does not return anything for me.

Comment: Is the bot id garunteed to be a single character?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala the bot id will be either `1` or `2`

Comment: @Magenta Did you press the pull answers button in the gui and click yes? That should fill it with answers

Comment: There is a bug where bots timing out (my Ruby bot was timing out a lot) cause crashes in the server code. [I've sent a pull request to fix it.](https://github.com/muddyfish/PPCG-Life/pull/1)

Comment: @muddyfish when i pull answers, that works, and the different bots can be selected. However, the rest of the gui is blank.

Comment: You need to click run? Try moving the window about if that doesn't work, if stuff starts miraculously appearing I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: What is the exact format of the "dictionary" in the board

Comment: Is it {'(y1,x1)',id1,'(y2,x2)',id2,(y3,x3),id3} etc...

Comment: If my bot tries to activate more than 30 cells what happens?

Comment: Are additional cells ignored or do i lose a turn?

Comment: +1. You deserve the AED award for bringing this great question out of the sandbox!

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala the dictionary format can be found in the chat link in the question, additional cells get filtered out. agtoever Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am so needy, but if someone would like to take a look at the "Troll Bot", and run it. I would like to see it tested so I can optimize it. The client arena wont work as I'm on a windows machine and the hardcoded command limit will prevent me from seeing the whole game.  If anyone would let me know if it worked for them. That would be great!

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala why won't it work on windows?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Windows commandline commands have a hardcoded limit of 8191 (to my knowledge, there might be a shell that beats the limit). The input to these programs is a command line argument, and considering the 1000x1000 board the input passed in (which is formatted to list every single active cell) can easily fly past that limit

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny oh, okay. Can you run a command in a file?

Comment: If I try to activate a cell thats already activated is that ignored?

Comment: Rohan, yes. It still counts as one of the 30 though

Comment: @muddyfish if you are having trouble running all the bots together you could probably get a [cloud9 partition](http://c9.io) and run it from there? I'm just sad that my bot is the only one that uses a strategy based on the opponent's board state instead of dropping things wherever

Comment: The problem's been fixed, just testing now.

Comment: It's a real shame that there weren't too many bots for this one... I feel like the Windows problem was a big issue, but there's nothing that can be done about that now

Comment: @muddyfish You should select mark the winning bot as accepted and post the scores if the competition is indeed over as of July 14th.

Comment: I'm not accepting yet because I'm waiting on trollbot. I still can't run it

Comment: @muddyfish When are the scores going to be up?

Comment: @Magenta When I get them (I'd completely forgotten about this even though it's been in a constantly open tab), I'm running it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python 3, Exploder

Puts small exploders around the place, with no regard to whether there is already a block there.

```
from random import randint
import sys,json,copy
q=json.loads(sys.argv[1])
x=q["x_size"];y=q["y_size"];F=[[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,2]];D=[]
for g in [0]*5:
 X=randint(0,x);Y=randint(0,y);A=copy.deepcopy(F)
 for C in A:C[0]+=Y;C[1]+=X
 D+=A
print(D)
```

Comment: I can't believe that after all my work setting up block-making switches for indefinite growth and a system specifically built to demolish growth structures, a simple exploder-based system bested mine in combat :o

Comment: I don't know how it does either, because I can't run the controller for whatever reason.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, InterruptingBlockMaker

Instead of initializing gliders like the TrainingBot, it tries to create a [5x5 block-making switch machine as mentioned on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns) at a random point in the maze. Then, with its remaining activations, it just finds enemy points and tries to pepper the nearby area with your cells in an attempt to interrupt them from growing and possibly messing up their patterns. Your cells will die in the next generation, but maybe they also stopped some growth to slow down your opponent!

v2: Optimized slightly (?) to try to minimize timeouts.

v3: Optimized interruption code to pre-sample a subset of active blocks before rejecting our own cell locations, to prevent timeouts further at the cost of some effectiveness in the interrupt cell attacks.

```
require 'json'

class Range
  def product range2
    self.to_a.product range2.to_a
  end
end

args = JSON.parse(ARGV[0])
bot_id = args["bot_id"]
width  = args["x_size"]
height = args["y_size"]
board  = args["board"]

generator = [[2,2], [2,3], [2,6], [3,2], [3,5], [4,2], [4,5], [4,6], [5,4], [6,2], [6,4], [6,5], [6,6]]

targets = []

iterations = 50
gen_location = nil
while !gen_location && iterations > 0
  y = rand height - 9
  x = rand width  - 9
  temp = (0...9).product(0...9).map{|_y, _x| [y + _y, x + _x]}
  if temp.all?{|_y,_x| !board["(#{y},#{x})"]}
    gen_location = temp
    targets += generator.map{|_y, _x| [y + _y, x + _x]}
  end

  iterations -= 1
end

enemies = board.keys.sample(100).reject {|k| board[k] == bot_id}
interrupts = []
enemies.each do |location|
  y, x = location.scan(/\d+/).map &:to_i
  interrupts |= ((y-1)..(y+1)).product((x-1)..(x+1)).reject{|y, x| gen_location.include?([y,x]) || board["(#{y},#{x})"]}
end

targets += interrupts.sample(30 - targets.size)

puts JSON.dump(targets)
```

Comment: @muddyfish thanks, that fixed it! Now the only issue is that Windows command line commands have a hardcoded limit of 8191, which means that at a certain point in the simulation the bots will crash from being unable to parse the truncated JSON string. It's an OS issue, so I guess I have have to look into a Linux cloud box or something in order to test my bot~

Comment: @muddyfish I already mentioned that Windows has problems because of the command line limit, that last error was on Cloud9 which is ostensibly a Linux box. How does my bot fare on your Linux box (since you implied that you had one)?

Comment: Turns out I hadn't committed it but the numbers in `bot_score` show how many wins each bot has against other bots

Comment: All right, thanks! Unfortunately, Cloud9 indeed does not have a GUI and Windows still can't run the simulation without breaking its command limit eventually, but at least I got a brief look into how the bots fare against each other. Also, I get to see my bot fight against itself to the end some times because they keep attacking each other and preventing enough growth to break the character limit, although it does time out occasionally...

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, TrainingBot

Because everyone needs one of these!

```
import random, copy
import sys, json

args = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
bot_id = args["bot_id"]
x_size = args["x_size"]
y_size = args["y_size"]
cur_tick = args["tick_id"]
board = args["board"]

glider = [[1,2],[2,1],[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]]

x_add = random.randrange(x_size)
y_add = random.randrange(y_size)
new_glider = copy.deepcopy(glider)
for coord in new_glider:
    coord[0]+=y_add
    coord[1]+=x_add
move = new_glider
print json.dumps(move)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java, Troll Bot

Troll Bot has thought about it, and he realizes he does NOT care about the enemy. In fact he just spams these factories to produce more of his guys randomly all over the map. After a while he realized that any additional cells are best used in clumps. These blocks of four cells will stick together and stop gliders in their tracks! He does not think he just fights. Also he is a big supporter of verbose object oriented programming. The troll also assumes that coords are in the format y,x, and he is asking to be tested. Just put him in a file called "TrollBot.java", and he'll be set!

```
package trollbot;

/**
 *
 * @author Rohans
 */
public class TrollBot{
public static class coord{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public coord(int inX,int inY){
        x = inX;
        y = inY;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return"["+x+","+y+"]";
    }
}
    /**
     * Input the JSON as the first cla
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String JSON="{\"bot_id\":1,\"y_size\":1000,\"x_size\":1000,\"board\":{}}";
    String[] JArray=args[0].split(",");
       int botId=Integer.parseInt(JSON.charAt(10)+"");
    int xSize=Integer.parseInt(JArray[2].substring(JArray[2].indexOf(":")+1));
    int ySize=Integer.parseInt(JArray[1].substring(JArray[1].indexOf(":")+1));
    int[][] board = new int[xSize][ySize];//0 indexed
//todo: parse the board to get an idea of state
    String soldiers="[";    
//for now just ignore whats on the board and put some troll cells on
    //Attempts to create 3 10 cells factories of cells, hoping it does not place it on top of allies
    //Then puts random 2/2 blocks
  boolean[][] blockspam=new boolean[10][8];
  blockspam[7][1]=true;
  blockspam[5][2]=true;
  blockspam[7][2]=true;
  blockspam[8][2]=true;
  blockspam[5][3]=true;
  blockspam[7][3]=true;
  blockspam[5][4]=true;
  blockspam[3][5]=true;
  blockspam[1][6]=true;
  blockspam[3][6]=true;
  for(int z=0;z<3;z++){
     int xOffSet=(int) (Math.random()*(xSize-11));
     int yOffSet=(int) (Math.random()*(ySize-9));
     //stay away from edges to avoid odd interactions
     for(int i=0;i<blockspam.length;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<blockspam[i].length;j++){
             if(blockspam[i][j])
             soldiers+=new coord(j+yOffSet,i+xOffSet).toString()+",";
         }
     }
  }
  soldiers=soldiers.substring(0,soldiers.length()-1);
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            int y=(int ) (Math.random()*(ySize-1));
            int x = (int) (Math.random()*(xSize-1));
      soldiers+=new coord(y,x).toString()+",";
                          soldiers+=new coord(y+1,x).toString()+",";
                          soldiers+=new coord(y,x+1).toString()+",";
                          soldiers+=new coord(y+1,x).toString()+",";

  }
  soldiers+="\b]";

  System.out.println(soldiers);
  //GO GO GO! Lets rule the board
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, RandomBot

This bot has trouble making intelligent decisions, but it at least knows not to try to place things on top of other things.  It'll randomly create gliders, boats, [C/2 Orthagonal](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/C/2_orthogonal)s, and 2x2 blocks with various orientations, ensuring that when they're placed they're not overlapping with something else, ally or enemy.

This bot wasn't tested, seeing as I'm receiving all sorts of errors when I try to run the GUI.  Also, I used the TrainingBot as the base and just edit, so any similarities in code is probably because of that.

```
import random, copy
import sys, json
args = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
bot_id = args["bot_id"]
x_size = args["x_size"]
y_size = args["y_size"]
board = args["board"]
occupied = [tuple(key) for key,value in iter(board.items())]
cellsleft=30
move=[]
choices = [[[1,2],[2,1],[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]],
           [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]],
           [[0,1],[1,0],[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3],[4,3],[5,2],[5,0]],
           [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[2,1],[2,2]]]
while cellsleft>0:
    x_add = random.randrange(x_size)
    y_add = random.randrange(y_size)
    new_glider = copy.deepcopy(random.choice(choices))
    randomdirection = random.choice([[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,-1]])
    maxy=max([y[0] for y in new_glider])
    maxx=max([x[1] for x in new_glider])
    for coord in new_glider:
        coord[0]=coord[0]*randomdirection[0]+y_add
        coord[1]=coord[1]*randomdirection[1]+x_add
        cellsleft-=1
    set([tuple(x) for x in new_glider]) 
    if not set([tuple(x) for x in new_glider]) & (set(occupied)|set([tuple(x) for x in move])) and cellsleft>0:
        if min(y[0] for y in new_glider)<0: new_glider = [[y[0]+maxy,y[1]] for y in new_glider]
        if min(y[1] for y in new_glider)<0: new_glider = [[y[0],y[1]+maxx] for y in new_glider]
        move += new_glider
    elif set([tuple(x) for x in new_glider]) & (set(occupied)|set([tuple(x) for x in move])):
        cellsleft+=len(new_glider)

print(json.dumps(move))
```

Comment: The GUI is most likely failing because of your `print(sys.argv[1])` on line 3, which messes up the output (the simulator expects only the string of coordinates you want to wake up). Also, the last line of your program is missing a closing paren.

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny  The GUI was failing on the training bot and the Ruby bot as well.  I removed that line, though, and added back in the closing paren (I think that latter one was a copy-paste error).

Comment: What operating system are you on, and what errors appear in the command line when you run it? Currently it's a known bug that Windows cannot properly run the sim because of arguments passed through command line being truncated when they exceed the command line character limit of around 8000.

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny I'm using Windows 10, and I've gotten... well, a lot of errors.  The first thing was BeautifulSoup not wanting to find `html5lib`, then not finding the folder containing all the bots (I had to change the code for both of these), and since then the running of either Python bot has resulted in a non-0 return code 1.

Comment: Windows still can't run the code if there are too many active cells on the screen... But as for your other errors, it might be because TrainingBot wants Python 2?

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny Might be it.  I'll try it with your bot and see if that helps things at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41885/discussion-between-fawful-and-kevin-lau-not-kenny).

Answer (score 3):

### Python, GuyWithAGun

He's a guy, he's got a gun; he's mad. He just dumps glider guns everywhere with no regard to what anyone else is doing

```
import random, copy
import sys, json

args = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
bot_id = args["bot_id"]
x_size = args["x_size"]
y_size = args["y_size"]
tick_id = args["tick_id"]
board = args["board"]

start_squares = [[0,5],[2,5],[1,6],[2,6],
                 [35,3],[36,3],[35,4],[36,4]]
gun = [[11,5],[11,6],[11,7],
       [12,4],[12,8],
       [13,3],[13,9],
       [14,3],[14,9],
       [15,6],
       [16,4],[16,8],
       [17,5],[17,6],[17,7],
       [18,6],
       [21,3],[21,4],[21,5],
       [22,3],[22,4],[22,5],
       [23,2],[23,6],
       [25,1],[25,2],[25,6],[25,7]]

templates = [start_squares, gun]

def add_squares(pos, coords):
    new_squares = copy.deepcopy(coords)
    for coord in new_squares:
        coord[0]+=pos[0]
        coord[1]+=pos[1]
    return new_squares

def get_latest_pos():
    seed, template_id = divmod(tick_id, 2)
    random.seed(seed)
    cur_pos = [random.randrange(y_size),
               random.randrange(x_size)]
    cur_template = templates[template_id]
    try:
        return add_squares(cur_pos, cur_template)
    except IndexError:
        return []

move = get_latest_pos()

print json.dumps(move)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, SquareBot

Puts squares everywhere- maybe

Squares are static objects in Life- they do not move. So if I place enough inert objects around the place, the gliders and explosions that others create will possibly be blocked, or at least dampened.

-Adapted from TrainingBot

```
from random import randint
import sys,json,copy
args=json.loads(sys.argv[1])
x=args["x_size"];y=args["y_size"]
square=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]];D=[]
for g in range(7):
 X=randint(0,x);Y=randint(0,y)
 A=copy.deepcopy(square)
 for C in A:C[0]+=Y;C[1]+=X
 D+=A
print(D)
```

Although I am having trouble testing it

Comment: [You might be able to get some help from this chat discussion on the RandomBot.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41885/discussion-between-fawful-and-kevin-lau-not-kenny)

Comment: I can confirm that this bot does in fact do what it's meant to - and it helped me find and fix a bug in the controller